# Synchronize clocks with chrony without internet access

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have no experience in this field but I have the task to synchronize a number of Ubuntu 18.04 machines on a local network not connected to the internet. I tried using chrony following the instructions found [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/995113/682254), but when I tried `systemctl enable chronyd` I received this error

```
Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on linked unit file chronyd.service
```

I tried disabling it first, which showed

```
Removed /etc/systemd/system/chronyd.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/chrony.service
```

but now I can't start it or enable it, showing this error instead

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file chronyd.service does not exist.
```

while I can see the file being present in the `/etc/systemd/system/` folder.
I'm at loss here on what I should do. I tried uninstalling and installing chrony again without success.

Comment: After making changes to the underlying file structure you may want to start with `systemctl daemon-reload` (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload` if you're not logged in as root)  to have systemd reload all unit files and recreate the entire dependency tree.

Comment: Thank you @Bob. I tried as you said but it would still show `chronyd.service` as missing. I purged chrony and reinstalled it. After applying the changes to the configuration I used `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` before enabling it, but it still showed the error `Refusing to operate on linked unit file chronyd.service` as before

Comment: Just a wild hunch: trying using 'chrony.service' (not 'chronyd.service') in your systemctl commands.

Comment: I restarted the machine and chrony seems to be working fine now, even if `enable` still doesn't work. Weird!

Comment: Would you mind updating the title to something a little bit more relevant to the problem?  Something like "Unable to enable or start Chrony service"?  The disconnected nature of your environment has turned out to be unrelated to actual issue, but the actual cause was identified and answered thus this is still a useful question/answer.

Comment: For RH9 is chronyd.service

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct answer to resolve the issue.

systemctl enable chrony

> Just a wild hunch: trying using 'chrony.service' (not
> 'chronyd.service') in your systemctl commands. –  Brandon Xavier  May
> 19, 2021 at 14:58